# VBA WebBrowser layer level background

Tags: excel, vba

i'm currently trying to set my WebBrowser1 level back, in edit mode it looks like it's behind the lebels but when i run it, it's in the foreground. with `Z0rder` didint work

```
WebBrowser1.ZOrder 0
LabelPathFolder.ZOrder 1
```

see pictures

[image: here in edit modus in background level]

after runing the userform:

[image: foreground]

how can i handle it, so its on backlevel

Update: as video: in edit modus, you can see that the labels are on the webbrowser as layer, but after i run the code, the webbrowser is on the label so the labels isnt visible

[[image: gif][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvac.gif)
[[image: gif2][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIjtE.gif)

Comment: Those screenshots do not really covey anything useful...

Comment: sec doing new ones than.

Comment: @TimWilliams added 2 new gifs, hope its now better to understand

Comment: also tried this
WebBrowser1.ZOrder 0
LabelPathFolder.ZOrder 1
but didnt work

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible to do what you want?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite understand what you meant, sorry. Do you think I'm missing something easy or that it's not possible?
i basically want a background (animated one i already have gif) which moves behind my labels and everything

Comment: From my testing it doesn't seem possible to put the web browser control in the background.

Comment: what can i do instead of using a web browser so that i have an animated image (gif) in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this seemed to work for me: add a frame and put the browser control in that frame (size the frame to fill the form).  Add each other control in a frame and set the zorder of that  frame using (eg) `Me.Frame2.ZOrder msoBringToFront`

Eg:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim ctl As Object
   
    FitForm Me.Frame1
    FitForm Me.WebBrowser1
    Me.Frame1.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://www.example.com"
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name Like "Frame*" And ctl.Name <> "Frame1" Then
            ctl.ZOrder msoBringToFront
        End If
    Next ctl
    
End Sub

Private Sub FitForm(obj)
    With obj
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = Me.Width
        .Height = Me.Height
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: it worked, but i cant do frames transparent right? i mean i have now the gray background from the frame. This doesnt see good with frame background.

Comment: You need one frame for any control which needs to be above the browser.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Thank you very much you helped me again. I just have fps problems through it will look like this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpJ9R0ygkk4&ab_channel=AndiSetiadi but he dont explains how he is doing that :D